# ruby roo puts column from parsing

Tags: ruby, excel, rubygems, ruby-roo

I'm total newbie in programming...thanks in advance for all those who will answer me..
I'm trying to print the columns starting from a search. Actually my excel is composed like this:

```
|      | Header | Header | Header | Header |
|Header|Server 1|Server 2|Server 3|Server 4|
|Header|  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |
|Header|  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |
|Header|  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |
```

This is my code but the output is not what I'm looking for....

```
fo_set_parse = xls.parse(:header_search => ['Server'], :clean => true)
fo_set_parse.each do |row|
row.each do |key,value| 
    if value != nil 
        puts "#{value}"
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like to print in the same excel style starting from a "Server" search..The number of "Server" change every time, so I'can't use something like

```
1.upto(xls.last_column) do |col|
   server1 = xls.cell(2,col)
   server2 = xls.cell(3,col)
   server3 = xls.cell(4,col)
   server4 = xls.cell(5,col)
   puts "#{server1}\t #{server2}\t #{server3}\t #{server4}\t"
end
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with roo (and at a quick glance, it doesn't seem like there are many examples to pull from), but how about:

```
data_row_definitions = {
  :data_a => 2,                          # i.e. data_a is stored in row 2 for all servers
  :data_b => 3,
  :data_c => 4,
}
server_columns = 2.upto(xls.last_column) # or whatever columns the servers are listed

server_columns.map do |server_col|
  data_for_server = Hash[
    data_row_definitions.map do |data_name, row|
      cell_value = xls.cell(row, server_col)
      [data_name, cell_value]
    end
  ]
end
```

With a table like:

```
|       |Server 1|Server 2|Server N|
| dataA |       1|       3|       7|
| dataB |      10|      35|      14|
| dataC |     100|      95|      28|
```

(I would imagine) You would get the data structure:

```
[
  {
    "dataA" => 1,
    "dataB" => 10,
    "dataC" => 100,
  },
  {
    "dataA" => 3,
    "dataB" => 35,
    "dataC" => 95,
  },
  {
    "dataA" => 7,
    "dataB" => 14,
    "dataC" => 28,
  },
]
```

And should work for however many `N` servers/columns you have due to every sever/column being enumerated in the `server_columns` variable.